# Strang, Introd. to Linear Algebra: Why do dimensions of nullspace and column space of space of 3x3 matrices sum to 9?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

> Consider the vector space $M$ of 3x3 matrices. Multiply every matrix
> $X$ in $M$ by
>
> $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&-1\\ -1&1&0\\ 0&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> and note that
>
> $$A \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 0\\
>  0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> (a) What matrices $X$ lead to $AX=$ zero matrix?
>
> (b) Which matrices
> have the form $AX$ for some matrix $X$?
>
> (a) finds the "nullspace" of that operation $AX$ and
> (b) finds the "column space". What are the dimensions of those two subspaces of $M$? Why do the dimensions add to $(n-r)+r=9$?

Let me put here the solution from the solution manual

> (a) $AX=0$ if each column of $X$ is a multiple of $(1,1,1)$;
> dim(nullspace)=3.
>
> (b) If $AX=B$ then all columns of $B$ add to zero; dimension of the
> B's is 6
>
> (c) $3+6=dim(M^{3x3})=9$ entries in a 3 x 3 matrix

Let me now provide my own solution.

$M$ has 9 dimensions, and any matrix of form

$$X=\begin{bmatrix} c\\ c\\ c\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix} a_1&a_2&a_3\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$

is such that $AX=$ zero matrix.

Intuitively, the vector space of such matrices has dimension 3: we can pick any numbers for the three variables $a_1, a_2, a_3$.

Now let's consider the "column space".

This is the set of all matrices $AX$ for some $X$ in $M$.

The matrices in (1) are a subspace of $M$.

Every matrix $Y$ not in this subspace generates some matrix $AY$ which is not the zero matrix. Now, this set of matrices does not include the zero matrix so this is not a subspace. If we were to include the zero matrix in this set, would it be a subspace of dimension 6? This seems intuitively to be the case but I don't know what it is that allows me to prove this.

It is not clear to me why it is that the dimension of the "nullspace" and the dimension of the "column space" in this example sum to the dimension 9 of $M$.

For vector spaces composed of vectors (not matrices), we can place vectors in the columns of a matrix. The matrix is $m x n$ with rank $r$. Vectors in the nullspace have $n$ coordinates, vectors in the column space have $m$ coordinates. The nullspace has $n-r$ dimensions, and the column space has $r$ dimensions. The sum of these dimensions is $n$. It is not clear to me why this is either.

It seems like spaces of matrices (say $n$ by $m$) are similar to a space of vectors of size 1 by $n\cdot m$.

Comment: Please make subject lines informative and useful. Truncated sentences are neither.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin My bad, I've fixed the title.

Comment: You are working in a 9 dimensional space (the space of all $3\times 3$ matrices). By the Rank-Nullity Theorem, the rank plus nullity of a linear transformation from this space will add up to 9.